# Sending email through G Suite using Golang

Tags: email, go, smtp, google-workspace

I've got a G Suite account set up and I enabled the SMTP relay service. The relay service is currently configured to accept mail from my webservers IP address only, not requiring SMTP authentication or TLS encryption.
[This link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) tells me that I should be able to send mail to smtp-relay.gmail.com on port 25 (or 465/587).

That's all well and good. I've got a very simple go script to send email here.

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "net/smtp"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        args := os.Args[1:]
        to := args[0]
        body := args[1]
        from := "[my g-suite user account name]"
        msg := "From: " + from + "\n" + "To: " + to + "\n" + 
                "Subject: Hello Friend\n\n" + body
        err := smtp.SendMail("smtp-relay.gmail.com:25",nil,
                from, []string{to}, []byte(msg))
        if err != nil {
                log.Printf("smtp err :%s\n",err)
        } else {
                log.Printf("Email sent\n")
        }

        log.Printf("email sent\n")
}
```

When I run this, I get the following panic

```
2018/11/29 12:24:22 smtp err :dial tcp 74.125.195.28:25: connect: no route to host
```

I understand what this error is telling me but I cant for the life of me resolve it. I thought it was a problem with my firewall settings. I've tried flushing my iptables and disabling ufw but I get the same result every time.

I've also tried sending mail from this webserver using mutt and sendmail (with similar settings).

Any suggestions on what I should be looking for? I have done a bunch of searching and tried several other scripts but always have the same result.

**EDIT**
After trying a few different options like regular gmail with an existing account, using sendmail or ssmtp I looked at tcpdump while trying to send mail. Wireshark shows that the communication with the mail server as "Communication administratively filtered". I'm taking that to mean the hosting provider is filtering ports 25,465 and 587 since I've tried them all and I've disabled my rules.

Comment: Did it work in mutt and/or sendmail?

Comment: No. Sorry I should have explained that. Mutt reported "network is unreachable" and sendmail reported "no route to host"

Comment: So you are having a network problem rather than a go problem. Are you trying this at home? A lot of providers block port 25 to prevent spammers from using their networks.

Comment: No this is on a VPS. 
I have tried flushing iptables and testing to see if there was something in my rule set blocking. But I guess there could be something going on in the actual providers setup?

Comment: You need to use port 587, not 25, and authenticate to Gmail (your code doesn't authenticate).

Comment: No route to host generally means that there is a more basic lack of connectivity, it would be a different error if the port was closed, I think.

Comment: @MichaelHampton If you follow the link you'll see that with G Suite 25 is a valid option, and you can either use authentication or allow a static IP address without authentication. This is what I'm doing.

Comment: Sure, it's valid for connecting to G Suite, but you have to actually be able to make that connection. Many hosting providers and ISPs block outgoing connections on port 25. Yours is probably one of them. Sometimes you can get them to unblock it if you have business service, but it's usually easier to just switch to port 587.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's a valid point. I'm going to abandon this current path and try switching to standard gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
My hosting provider was filtering SMTP ports. I opened a service ticket and had these filters adjusted. Mail works fine now